# erlang has no shared memory. So what happens with the sum function for example?

Tags: erlang

Erlang has no shared memory. Look at the sum function,

```
sum(H|T)->H+sum(T);
sum([])->0
```

So 
sum([1,2,3])=1+2+3+0

Now what happens? Does erlang creates an array with [1,1+2,1+2+3,1+2+3+0]?

Comment: I don't see why Erlang could possibly produce that list for the code you've posted. Did you mean to ask if it creates these 3 lists: `[1, 2, 3]`, `[2, 3]`, and `[3]`?

Comment: @Dogbert I don't know. I was wondering what Erlang does instead of using shared memory.  I thought maybe a list, but I have no idea.

Comment: 'no shared memory' just means, that no other processes or threads can access and alter memory allocated by an erlang process, this has nothing to do how erlang processes manage their own memory state. Instead of using a memory-block, other threads can also read or write to, erlang processes pass messages among each other to exchange information.

Comment: I do not think you know what *shared memory* actually means. You probably are referring to *immutable references* which is something completely different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a completely flawed premise.

Answer (score 8):

This is what happens:

```
sum([1,2,3]) = 1 + sum([2,3])
                      => sum[2, 3] =  2 + sum([3])
                                             => sum([3]) = 3 + sum([])
                                                                 => sum([]) = 0
```

Now `sum([3])` can be evaluated:

```
  sum([3]) = 3 + sum([]) = 3 + 0 = 3
```

which means that `sum([2, 3])` can be evaluated:

```
sum([2, 3]) = 2 + sum([3]) = 2 + 3 = 5
```

which means that `sum([1, 2, 3])` can be evaluated:

```
sum([1,2,3]) = 1 + sum([2,3]) = 1 + 5 = 6
```

**Response to comment:**

Okay, I figured what you were really asking about was `immutable variables`.  Suppose you have the following C code:

```
int x = 0;
x += 1;
```

Does that code somehow demonstrate `shared memory`?  If not, then C does not use shared memory for int variables...and neither does erlang.

> In C you introduce a variable, sum, give it an initial value, 0, and
>   after that you add values to it. Erlang does not do this. What does
>   Erlang do?

Erlang allocates a new frame on the stack for each recursive function call.  Each frame stores the local variables and their values, e.g. the parameter variables, for that particular function call.  There can be multiple frames on the stack each storing a variable named X, but they are separate variables, so none of the X variables is ever mutated--instead a new X variable is created for each new frame, and the new X is given a new value.

Now, if the stack really worked like that in erlang, then a recursive function that executed millions of times would add millions of frames to the stack and in the process would probably use up its allocated memory and crash your program.  To avoid using excessive amounts of memory, erlang employs `tail call optimization`, which allows the amount of memory that a function uses to remain constant.  Tail call optimization allows erlang to replace the first frame on the stack with a subsequent frame of the same size, which keeps the memory usage constant.  In addition, even when a function is not defined in a tail recursive format, like your `sum()` function, erlang can optimize the code so that it uses constant memory (see the [Seven Myths of Erlang Performance](http://The%20Seven%20Myths%20of%20Erlang%20Performance)).

In your `sum()` function, no variables are mutated and no memory is shared.  In effect, though, function parameter variables do act like mutable variables.

My first diagram above is a representation of the stack adding a new frame for each recursive function call.  If you redefine `sum()` to be tail recursive, like this:

```
sum(List)-> 
    sum(List, 0).

sum([H|T], Total) ->
    sum(T, Total+H);
sum([], Total)->
    Total.
```

then below is a diagram of a recursive function executing that represents frames being replaced on the stack to keep the memory usage constant:

```
sum([1, 2, 3]) => sum([1, 2, 3], 0)  [H=1, T=[2,3], Total=0]
               => sum([2,3], 1)      [H=2, T=[3], Total=1]
               => sum([3], 3])       [H=3, T=[], Total=3]
               => sum([], 6)         [Total=6]
=> 6
```

Comment: I know. My question is how Erlang does do this. In C you introduce a variable, sum, give it an initial value, 0, and after that you add values to it. Erlang does not do this. What does Erlang do?

Comment: @ericj, See my response to your comment at the end of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

you're making recursive calls. the scope for every function body is not terminated until it returns something. so the invariable variable H for every call will be kept till the base case happen.

it could be tail recursive with the help of an accumulator in the function arguments, which is lighter on memory by calculating the H part first and then calling the successor recursive and giving the calculated value to the successor as the accumulator.

so in both ways there's nothing used outside of your function scopes.